# What type of entries should the bibliography file in this Overleaf template have?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm trying to use [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/protocolo-propuesta-de-formato-de-presentacion-de-taller-de-investigacion-i/gqdqctbkdzyt) in Overleaf.

However, when I compile the code, I get everything except the reference section...

Since, in the overleaf link, nothing is said about the bibliography type of entry, I've tried using something like

```
@article{IMF09,
    author        = {{International Monetary Fund}},
    title         = {World Economic Outlook: Crisis and Recovery},
    year          = {2009},
    institution   = {International Monetary Fund. Research Dept.}
}
```

But it then asks to import biblatex package, and then a whole slew of commands must be added/changed...

Comment: The mere fact that you add this `.bib` entry should not automatically cause (La)TeX to want to import `biblatex`. The `.bib` entry is syntactically well formed and can be used with BibTeX and `biblatex`. (Semantically it can be improved, but that is the point of my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the template loads the IEEE class `IEEEtran` but then uses the outdated (and I think unofficial) `ieeetr` bibliography style. `IEEEtran` comes with its own set of official bibliography styles, so you should look into using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. (In fact that does not matter too much for the question at hand...)

In general I recommend not using publisher/journal classes like `IEEEtran` unless you plan to submit to that publisher/journal. In which case you should use the class exactly as documented.

---

Grey literature like this would normally not use the `@article` entry type. Only papers published in an academic journal should be `@article`s (`@article` is also OK for articles in non-academic journals, magazines and newspapers).

For reports like this, the best choice is usually `@techreport`. [`btxdoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) says the following about `@techreport`

> `techreport` A report published by a school or other institution, usually numbered within a series.
>   Required fields: `author`, `title`, `institution`, `year`.
>   Optional fields: `type`, `number`, `address`, `month`, `note`

In case of https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/WEO/Issues/2016/12/31/World-Economic-Outlook-April-2009-Crisis-and-Recovery-22575 I'd probably go with

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{imf09,
  author = {{International Monetary Fund}},
  title  = {World Economic Outlook, {April} 2009: Crisis and Recovery},
  year   = {2009},
  type   = {World Economic and Financial Surveys},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\cite{imf09}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: International Monetary Fund, “World economic outlook, April 2009: Crisis and recovery,” World Economic and Financial Surveys, 2009.]

You'll notice that I didn't include the (according to `btxdoc`) required field `institution`, because that would result in a doubled 'International Monetary Fund', which I found awkward

```
@techreport{imf09,
  author      = {{International Monetary Fund}},
  title       = {World Economic Outlook, {April} 2009: Crisis and Recovery},
  year        = {2009},
  type        = {World Economic and Financial Surveys},
  institution = {International Monetary Fund},
  address     = {Washington, D.C.},
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have one question, though.  When compiling, do I need to also run biblatex with your answer?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Yes-ish. The working code I posted would be compiled with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...; note that **you need to run BibTeX, which is a program, and not `biblatex`, which is a LaTeX package**). Many editors run a sequence like this automatically for you. Overleaf will run the required commands automatically when you click recompile. Note that I only used `filecontents` to be able to make the example self contained. In a real-world document you would add the entry to your normal `.bib` file.

Comment: But the gist of the answer (use `@techreport`) also applies when you generate your bibliography with `biblatex` (and consequently run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX).

Comment: When I compile your answer with bib(la)tex, in texmaker, I get the following error message «Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.13 INFO - Logfile is 'MWE.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find 'MWE.bcf'! INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)»

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. As I say: You need to compile *this* code with BibTeX. Apparently you are running Biber (which can only be used with `biblatex`; see the `INFO - This is Biber 2.13`). The gist of the answer can also be applied to `biblatex`, but the template you showed used BibTeX, so my full example code uses that as well. You can load `biblatex` in your document and use only the `.bib` code I've shown with `biblatex`. Or you can configure your editor to run BibTeX instead of Biber (essentially by following https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 backwards).